# openkm 6.3.0 community version & TomCat not runing on 64-bit Windows7

Tags: java, tomcat, dms, openkm

Yesterdy I spent hours test installing OpenKM Which is a Document management system I downloaded the Community Version on the following Machine :

- Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
- RAM 8GB

### Installed Web Servers

- Apache Web Server 2.4 to run PHP APPs
- IIS7.5 to run .NET APPs
- NI Web Server for National Instrument
- Tomcat to run JSP APPS

### Java Version

java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

### Tomcat Version

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
Server built:   Mar 25 2014 06:20:16
Server number:  7.0.53.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_31-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

### Runing `configtest.bat`

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
2015-03-03 16:55:03,693 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\DVTk\DVT\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;\lib\sigar;C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\lib\sigar;.
2015-03-03 16:55:04,025 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol- Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
2015-03-03 16:55:04,056 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol- Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
2015-03-03 16:55:04,063 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Initialization processed in 709 ms
```

### Home Environment Variable

```
    FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
    HOMEDRIVE=C:
    HOMEPATH=\Users\MyACC
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31
    JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
    KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE
    LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\MyACC\AppData\Local
    LOGONSERVER=\\PC_NAME
    MKL_SERIAL=YES
    NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
    OS=Windows_NT
    Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\DVTk\DVT\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin
    PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
    PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 30 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
    PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
    PROCESSOR_REVISION=1e05
    ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
    ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
    ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
    ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
    PROMPT=$P$G
    PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
    PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
    SystemDrive=C:
    SystemRoot=C:\Windows
    TEMP=C:\Users\MyACC\AppData\Local\Temp
    TMP=C:\Users\MyACC\AppData\Local\Temp
    USERDOMAIN=PC_NAME
    USERNAME=MyACC
    USERPROFILE=C:\Users\MyACC
    VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
    VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
    windir=C:\Windows
```

I stopped Apache Server 
NI Web Server which is used the port 8080

### running the command `catalina.bat start`

```
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,478 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener- The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\DVTk\DVT\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\php;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;\lib\sigar;C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\lib\sigar;.
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,811 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol- Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,842 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol- Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,849 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Initialization processed in 707 ms
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,920 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService- Starting service Catalina
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,920 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine- Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
    2015-03-03 17:11:05,967 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application archive C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\webapps\OpenKM.war
    2015-03-03 17:11:22,228 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase- ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OpenKM]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/openkm/core/AccessDeniedException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:400)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.openkm.core.AccessDeniedException
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
        ... 24 more
    2015-03-03 17:11:22,235 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Error deploying web application archive C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\webapps\OpenKM.war
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/OpenKM]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    2015-03-03 17:11:22,240 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig- Deploying web application directory C:\openkm-6.3.0-community\tomcat\webapps\ROOT
    2015-03-03 17:11:23,691 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator- Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [521] milliseconds.
    2015-03-03 17:11:23,715 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol- Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080"]
    2015-03-03 17:11:23,723 [main] INFO  org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol- Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-127.0.0.1-8009"]
    2015-03-03 17:11:23,724 [main] INFO  org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina- Server startup in 17874 ms
```

### Finally

```
HTTP Status 404 - /OpenKM
```

As seen above , it looks like the Tomcat Server not Starting correctly , The OpenKM DMS bundle contain the java and tomcat server , I am not sure if there are any conflicting with other applications and services.

Any Help will be appreciate (:

Answer (score 1):

There are few other configuration that you need to do which I believe is not mentioned in their documentation

- OpenKM.cfg has to be updated
  hibernate.hbm2ddl=create
  for the first time until there are no issues in server startup.
- context.xml 
  Uncomment the Resource tag for hsqldb(A file based repository, which comes default with OpenKM)
- There are few other jar files which I believe is not present in tomcat lib folder which is required for OpenKM
  spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar, mail-1.4.7.jar, log4j-initializer.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar, jta-1.1.jar, jstl-1.2.jar, hsqldb.jar
  If the above jars are already present then skip step#3